# Returning a reference can work?

Tags: c++

I used to think returning a reference is bad as our returned reference will refer to some garbage value. But this code works (`matrix` is a class):

```
const int max_matrix_temp = 7;
matrix&get_matrix_temp()    
{
   static int nbuf = 0;  
   static matrix buf[max_matrix_temp];  

   if(nbuf == max_matrix_temp)    
      nbuf = 0;  

   return buf[nbuf++];
} 

matrix& operator+(const matrix&arg1, const matrix&arg2)
{  
    matrix& res = get_matrix_temp();
    //...  
    return res;
}
```

What is `buf` doing here and how does it save us from having garbage values?

Comment: What do you have against spaces?

Comment: `matrix& res max_matrix_temp();` does that even compile?

Comment: [Static variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no `buf` declared anywhere, which means it doesn't go out of scope with function return, so it's okay. (it actually looks like it's meant to be `matrixbuf` which is also fine, because it's `static`).

**EDIT:** Thanks to R. Martinho Fernandes for the guess. Of course it is `matrix buf`, so it makes `buf` static array in which temporary is allocated to make sure it doesn't get freed when the function returns and therefore the return value is still valid.

Comment: I suppose it's meant to be `matrix buf[...]`, as in, an array of `matrix` named `buf`.

Comment: There is no temporary allocated here. Static storage duration and temporaries are different concepts.

Comment: @RobKennedy, temporary not in the sense of being deallocated when leaving the scope, it is temporary, because the ring nature of the buffer suggests that at some point old references may point to the object that weren't intended for them.

Answer (score 2):

`buf` is declared as `static`, meaning it retains it's value between calls to the function:

```
static matrix buf[max_matrix_temp];
```

i.e. it's not created on the stack as `int i = 0;` would be (a non-static local variable), so returning a reference to it is perfectly safe.

This following code *is* dangerous, because the memory for the variable's value is on the stack, so when the function returns and we move back up the stack to the previous function, all of the memory reservations local to the function cease to exist:

```
int * GetAnInt()
{
  int i = 0;  // create i on the stack
  return &i;  // return a pointer to that memory address
}
```

Once we've returned, we have a pointer to a piece of memory on the stack, and with dumb luck it will hold the value we want because it's not been overwritten yet — but the reference is invalid as the memory is now free for use as and when space on the stack is required.

Comment: IOW, don't return references to *local* variables.

Comment: @xeo i still don't get it .please enlighten properly

Comment: @Xeo, IOW, don't return references unless you understand what you're doing (applies to the rest of possible activities as well).

Comment: @Michael: Now that's just wrong. You return references all the time in C++, think member functions.

Comment: @Xeo, I don't think Michael was suggesting that you shouldn't return them, I think he was suggesting that the OP doesn't know what he's doing - which is a relatively small leap of faith given the original question.

Comment: @Xeo, why understanding hurts then? Suppose you're returning references from member of the temporary?

Comment: @LaceySnr, I wouldn't go for saying the OP doesn't know what he's doing, he's trying to figure out what someone else did and why. Which is definitely not a bad thing to do.

Comment: That's true, it was probably a little harsh but even a little research would have turned up the answer.

Comment: @LaceySnr, I dunno. Given the knowledge and understanding we have it needs no research. I wouldn't know where to start if all you know is someone's statement that returning references is to be avoided. I think what the OP has done actually qualifies for a little research.

Comment: @Xeo, there's nothing inherently wrong with returning a reference to a local variable. The code in the question demonstrates that.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Right, that should've been "to *non-static local* variables".

Answer (score 0):

This is safe up to a point, but very dangerous.  The returned reference
can't dangle, but if client code keeps it around, at some future point,
the client is in for a big surprise, as his value suddenly changes to a
new return value.  And if you call `get_matrix_temp` more than
`max_matrix_temp` times in a single expression, you're going to end up
overwriting data as well.

In the days before `std::string`, in code using `printf`, I used this
technique for returning conversions of user defined types, where a
`"%s"` specifier was used, and the argument was a call to a formatting
function.  Again, `max_matrix_temp` was the weak point: a single
`printf` which formatted more instances of my type would output wrong
data.  It was a bad idea then, and it's a worse idea now.