# how returning reference work here

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning a reference can work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924966/returning-a-reference-can-work)

Why this code works (`matrix` is a class):

```
const int max_matrix_temp = 7;
matrix&get_matrix_temp()    
{
   static int nbuf = 0;  
   static matrix buf[max_matrix_temp];  

   if(nbuf == max_matrix_temp)    
      nbuf = 0;  

   return buf[nbuf++];
} 

matrix& operator+(const matrix&arg1, const matrix&arg2)
{  
    matrix& res = get_matrix_temp();
    //...  
    return res;
}
```

**What is `buf` doing here and how does it save us from having garbage values and why it is declared `static` ?** please enlighten properly..

Comment: As indicated in the answers to the original question you asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924966/returning-reference/8924994#8924994) it's declared static as otherwise it would cease to exist once the function completes, meaning any reference to an element in the array would be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you why code is organized as it is, but having static there makes it survive function exit. If static would not be used, then it would be allocated on stack and rewritten later.